# Dynamically created text inputs doesn't resize width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

One quick question i am trying to  auto-size the input text fields according to user inputs and i have some problems with the dynamically created input text ones, instead the others are functioning.

Here is the javascript , i am using:

```
<script>
(function($){
        $.fn.autoGrowInput = function(o) {

            o = $.extend({
                maxWidth: 1000,
                minWidth: 0,
                comfortZone: 70
            }, o);

            this.filter('input:text').each(function(){

                var minWidth = o.minWidth || $(this).width(),
                    val = '',
                    input = $(this),
                    testSubject = $('<tester/>').css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: -9999,
                        left: -9999,
                        width: 'auto',
                        fontSize: input.css('fontSize'),
                        fontFamily: input.css('fontFamily'),
                        fontWeight: input.css('fontWeight'),
                        letterSpacing: input.css('letterSpacing'),
                        whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
                    }),
                    check = function() {

                        if (val === (val = input.val())) {return;}

                        // Enter new content into testSubject
                        var escaped = val.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/\s/g,'&nbsp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
                        testSubject.html(escaped);

                        // Calculate new width + whether to change
                        var testerWidth = testSubject.width(),
                            newWidth = (testerWidth + o.comfortZone) >= minWidth ? testerWidth + o.comfortZone : minWidth,
                            currentWidth = input.width(),
                            isValidWidthChange = (newWidth < currentWidth && newWidth >= minWidth)
                                                 || (newWidth > minWidth && newWidth < o.maxWidth);

                        // Animate width
                        if (isValidWidthChange) {
                            input.width(newWidth);
                        }

                    };

                testSubject.insertAfter(input);

                $(this).bind('keyup keydown blur update', check);

            });

            return this;

        };

    })(jQuery);

    $('input').autoGrowInput();

</script>
```

this is how i create the text input fields :

```
                var tracktitleinput = document.createElement('input');
                tracktitleinput.setAttribute('type', "text");
                tracktitleinput.setAttribute('name', "tracktitle");
                tracktitleinput.setAttribute("required", true);
                tracktitleinput.setAttribute("placeholder",
                        "Required Field");
                tracktitleinput.setAttribute("class", "required");
```

and it does works perfectly with this ones :

```
<input type="text" id="releasename" name="releasename" required="true" placeholder="Required Field" />
```

Comment: Configure `.autoGrowInput()` for the dynamically created input also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they don't exist when you call `$('input').autoGrowInput();` I'm not sure why you'd expect them to have that functionality attached to them. jQuery isn't magic, it doesn't automatically know that code you ran when the page loaded is supposed to apply to elements that didn't exist then, unless you explicitly tell it to (and that only works for events via event delegation).

You'll need to call your plugin again when creating the dynamically added elements:

```
$(tracktitleinput).autoGrowInput();
```

Comment: It doesn't work i tried like that       var tracksubtitleinput = document
        .createElement('input');
      tracksubtitleinput.setAttribute('type', "text");
      tracksubtitleinput.setAttribute('name', "tracksubtitle");
      tracksubtitleinput.setAttribute("onkeyup","autoGrowInput()");
      $(tracksubtitleinput).autoGrowInput(); both of them don't work

Comment: @Ducaz035 Try adding it as part of the document before calling `$(tracksubtitleinput).autoGrowInput();`?

Answer (score 1):

When you create new inputs, you need to call the `autoGrowInput()` function for those elements:

```
var $newInput = $('<input/>', {
    type : 'text',
    name : 'tracktitle',
    required : 'true',
    placeholder : 'Required Field',
    class : 'required'
}).autoGrowInput();
```

Comment: how can i call in this example , var tracksubtitleinput = document
        .createElement('input');
      tracksubtitleinput.setAttribute('type', "text");
      tracksubtitleinput.setAttribute('name', "tracksubtitle"); i don t know how many input i will create before the user inputs it.

Comment: @Ducaz035 Now that I look again, it looks like the `autoGrowInput` function may only work after the element has been appended to the DOM. Can you post how you do that?

Comment: Okay i found the way now , i should have call it after appending the div. thanks for your help